# Meteor PKG zimme:active-route errors, Cannot install packages, various other issues (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I cannot seem to get a basic workspace to work.

> This issue is a known issue here:
> https://github.com/zimme/meteor-active-route/issues/52

---

Specs: Win7, 64bit.

I create a new app,

```
> meteor create example
```

That works fine.

I run the app,

```
> cd example
> meteor
```

---

I then add some packages to the packages file ([default] represents the default packages installed by `meteor create`, with `autopublish` and `insecure` removed.),

```
# [default]
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
erasaur:meteor-lodash
mquandalle:stylus
fortawesome:fontawesome
spiderable
fastclick
raix:handlebar-helpers
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
msavin:jetsetter
zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
```

I then start Meteor again:

```
> meteor

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
C:\Users\Pj\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_3
2\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Extracted archive '/C/Users/Pj/AppData/Local/Temp/.tmpkxwy69' should only
 contain one entry
```

[ full dump here http://pastebin.com/raw/jSA9N3AF ]

Happens every time, without fail.

---

## FAQ

Q. Have you restarted your machine?

- Yes. Too many times.

Q. Have you reinstalled Meteor?

- Multiple times, yes.

Q. Have you deleted the stuff in Local/Temp?

- Before, after, and during the installs.

Comment: I think you need to add one package at a time and see where it breaks. I know it's tedious, but you need to find the problem somehow :)

Comment: It's almost midnight here, I just posted this before bed, haha. I'll do this tomorrow, hopefully I can shed some light on it for both myself and anybody else with this problem. Thanks, @Mikkel , stay tuned

Comment: I'm about to sleep too, just a few minutes worth of stack overflow before z's

Comment: To save some time, you can use a technique called binary chop (or binary search) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm . Add half of the packages, if it's good, the problem is in the second half of the list. Keep chopping until you find it

Comment: Good *insert timezone here*! I'm doing that now, I'll keep you posted! Thanks for your help @Mikkel

Comment: Add a reply and I'll give you the points @Mikkel!

Comment: I'm in Aus (GMT+10) if that's what you want to know?

Comment: Please make a real answer; Don't add solutions to the question. Also, don't write "SOLVED" in the title.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen many people edit the question so people searching for the same thing find the answer. I'll do that now.

Comment: Thanks for your help on how to better use SO!

Comment: Might also change the title to reference the problem with zimme:active-route - the author might also appreciate a heads up of the problem too

Comment: It seems this might be a known problem: https://github.com/zimme/meteor-active-route/issues/52

Comment: I'll post my issue there as well, thanks @Mikkel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add one package at a time and see where it breaks. I know it's tedious, but you need to find the problem somehow :)

To save some time, you can use a technique called [binary chop (or binary search)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Add half of the packages, if it's good, the problem is in the second half of the list. Keep chopping until you find it.